# Sum of Highest 5 numbers in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am having a problem in query some data from database. My table is given below:

[image]

What i need is that sum of 5 highest total_marks from the table for each student.

[image]

Although i tried the code given below, but it is not returning what i expected.

```
SELECT s.studentid, SUM(s.total_marks)
FROM students s
WHERE s.sub_code IN (SELECT TOP 5 sub_code 
                 FROM students a 
                 WHERE a.studentid = s.studentid
                 ORDER BY total_marks DESC)
GROUP BY studentid
```

Please help me guys. Thanking you advance.

Comment: Is there a primary key on this table? What are the results you are getting from from your attempt?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the total_marks are the same? I.e. A student with 10 total_marks, of which there are 5 distinct values?

Answer (score 2):

You query could work **if there's unique/primary key** on `(studentId, subcode)`. At the moment, the query returns 6 records instead of 5 for `studentId = 1`, for example, beause of duplicate subcode `303`.
Usually table should have a unique key, may be you can add incremental `id` to rewrite your query like:

```
select s.*
from students as s
where
    s.id in (
        select top 5 a.id
        from students as a
        where a.studentId = s.studentId
        order by a.total_marks desc
    );
```

Or, if you have unique combinations of `(studentId, subcode, total_marks)`, you can use query like this:

```
select s.*
from students as s
where
    exists (
        select *
        from (
            select top 5 a.subcode, a.total_marks
            from students as a
            where a.studentId = s.studentId
            order by a.total_marks desc
        ) as b
        where b.subcode = s.subcode and b.total_marks = s.total_marks
    );
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/984ae/3)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

First you should select top 5 grades for each student -

```
select row_number() over (partition by studentid order by total_marks desc) as rank,
studentid, 
total_marks
from students
where rank <= 5
```

from there you'll be able to use this as a subquery, and use group_by and sum:

```
   select studentid, sum(total_marks)
   from
   (
        select row_number() over (partition by studentid order by total_marks desc) as    rank,
        studentid, 
        total_marks
        from students
        where rank <= 5 
   ) t
   group by studentid
```

Comment: AFAIK There is no support for analytic functions in **SQL Server 2000**. Therefore it won't work.

Comment: You also can't refer to an aliased column by it's alias in the where clause. Since the alias is in a subquery you could refer to the "rank" alias after aliasing the subquery as t, but the results may not be what you were after.

Comment: I see, that's too bad, I didn't notice the question mentioned SQL Server 2000

Comment: SQL Server 2000 is 13 years old now, might be time for an upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal, but the method you started to use requires a primary key column. You can simulate one with a temp table since SQL 2000.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (


StudentID INT,
  total_marks INT,
  ID INT Identity(1,1)
)

INSERT INTO #temp (
  StudentID,
  total_Marks
)
Select
  StudentID,
  total_marks
FROM Students

SELECT s.studentid, SUM(s.total_marks)
FROM #temp s
WHERE s.ID IN (SELECT TOP 2
                   a.ID
                 FROM #temp a 
                 WHERE a.studentid = s.studentid
                 ORDER BY total_marks DESC)
GROUP BY studentid
```

I think SQL 2000 may have a slightly more compact syntax for this, but SQL Fiddle won't let me test versions that old.

Please test this carefully. You will be dumping this entire table to a temp table and that's almost always a bad idea.

Also, ensure that there is some combination of fields not including the total that uniquely identifies a row, or consider adding a surrogate key column to the table.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad2ac/4/0)